# Unable to run tests with TestNG , Maven and Allure

Tags: java, maven, testng, allure

I'm working on a project which uses Allure framework with Java, TestNG and Maven. But I'm unable to run tests

Following is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <testng.version>6.3</testng.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium.version>
    <chromedriver.version>2.53.0</chromedriver.version>
    <mavensurefire.version>2.19</mavensurefire.version>
    <mavencompiler.version>3.5.1</mavencompiler.version>
    <mavensurefirereport.version>2.19</mavensurefirereport.version>
    <allure.version>1.4.16</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    <alluremaven.version>2.5</alluremaven.version>
    <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${chromedriver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavensurefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>

                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavencompiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${alluremaven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <allureResultsDirectory>${allure.results.directory}</allureResultsDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sI1x1.png[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project Cloud: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.xml.XmlTest.getLocalParameters()Ljava/util/Map;
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener.getCurrentSuiteTitle(AllureTestListener.java:225)
[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener.onStart(AllureTestListener.java:76)

Comment: How do you run your tests? How does testng.xml look like?